# Button's style is adding unknown attribute - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-layout-weight

I am trying to achieve the look of Facebook's event page and am having trouble copying their three buttons that say if a person is going to an event.

I am trying to achieve this,

[image]

Mine currently looks like this,

[image]

This is the XML for the buttons

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_holder"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_going"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:text="Going"
            android:background="@drawable/item_left_button_background"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_maybe"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:text="Maybe"
            android:background="@drawable/item_middle_button_background"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_decline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:text="Decline"
            android:background="@drawable/item_right_button_background"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I do not know where the extra `Padding` or `Margin` is coming from above and below my buttons. I have tried `android:padding="0dp"` and `android:layout_margin="0dp"` on the buttons but it had no effect.

My best guess is it might have something to do with the `layout_weight` attribute. This may give the buttons a certain height based on their width, if this is the case then how can I make the buttons shorter?

Comment: instead of giving the layout_width as wrap_content give a specific height to it then you will achieve what you want

Comment: Try to use ImageButton and set background with :android:src=""

Comment: Buttons have `android:minHeight=48dp` and `android:minWidth=88dp` (on Lollipop). That includes any padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS you are applying the background `item_left_button_background` so that must be an image or selector which consists images those images have a specific height. When you give the button height as `wrap_content` it will take by default what is height of the image so as per my suggestion give a specific height to the button or create the background images as per your required sizes

Comment: This worked well. I didn't think about the fact that the background's had a set height, since they are a `<layer-list>`. For anyone that may want to achieve this I went with `height="35dp"` to achieve the Facebook look.

Comment: thats great, if my answer helped you can accept it though :)